# Reference list of formula for org-mode tables

Tags: emacs, reference, formula, org-mode

An incredibly simple question, I'm surprised I couldn't answer it myself with Google.

I am currently building my expenses, job and time tracking system in Emacs org-mode using tables.

I know that I can use the formula "vsum()", I've also seen "vmean()".

I am looking for a reference list of the formula that you can use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See https://github.com/fniessen/stage-latex-dunkerque-2013/blob/master/org-mode-latex-export.pdf, slides 27 and 28 for the most common ones.

For others, look up the Calc manual.

Comment: Thank you. That was enough of a pointer to get me building my own reference list - in org mode table of course :)